# PHP image upload: works as an isolated example but not from my project code

Tags: php, image, upload

I have the most simple case of image upload. When I run this as a separate example it DOES work. When I incorporate the same .js code into my project's javascript code, and try the upload from my html page (.js and .php codes identical, id's and names adjusted etc.), it doesn't work.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 File API</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Upload Your Images</h1>
            <input type="file" name="images" id="images"/>
            <input type="submit" id="submitImages" onclick="submitImages()">

    <div id="response"></div>
        <ul id="image-list">

        </ul>
    </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="upload.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
function submitImages(){

    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData();
    }

    file = document.getElementById('images').files[0];

    if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        if (formdata) {
            formdata.append("images[]", file);
        }
    }   

    if (formdata) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res); 
            }
        });
    }   

}
```

php:

```
<?php

foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "uploads/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);
    }
}

echo "<h2>Successfully Uploaded Images</h2>";

?>
```

The message I get from server when I attempt the upload from my project:

```
POST-->POST:
Source
-----------------------------2656620091882 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[]"; filename="dock_2.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg ÿØÿáa"Exif��MM�*�� 
etc.

POST-->RESPONSE:
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: images in <b>C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Projects\DockMapper\add_edit_upload_images.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Projects\DockMapper\add_edit_upload_images.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<h2>Successfully Uploaded Images</h2>
```

It seems that something is sent to the server, but that it is not received on the server. When I run: print_r($_FILES); the array is empty. I spent probably two days over this and I couldn't find the problem. Any suggestions? Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
For example 
Jquery

```
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
    var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data)
    alert(form_data);                             
    $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data); 
                }
     });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Haru. I did try your code- it works good alone, but when I insert it into my .js file, I get the same problem.
The file seems to be sent to the server (it takes the same time for few MB to be uploaded in both cases). And I am uploading to the very same '/uploads' folder, meaning folder permissions are the same.
Only in this case it says : 'Undefined index: file in <b>C:\XAMPP\htdocs\...\upload1.php</b> on line
 <b>3</b><br />' etc.
 while in my case the undefined index and for loop were with respect to images[].
I have no idea what could it be. It drives me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was the issue:
In my project's html file, jquery was included inside the HEADER with these lines:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

It worked when I deleted those lines, and included ONLY the following ajax library, inside the FOOTER:

```
<html>
<body>
  ...
</body>
  ...
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  ...
</html>
```